# return statement not returning control to caller in java

Tags: java, return, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to practice binary trees in Java and tried to write a "isPresent" function. But the function isn't working if the argument (`testInt`) isn't the root node value. It is entering an infinite loop. I'm missing some silly thing I'm sure.

```
public class Node {
    // Attributes
    int value;
    Node leftChild;
    Node rightChild;

    // Constructor
    Node (int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    // Getter
    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    boolean isPresent(int testInt) {
        Node presentNode = this;
        while (presentNode != null) {
            if (presentNode.getValue() == testInt) {
                return true;
            } else if (testInt < presentNode.getValue()) {
                presentNode.leftChild.isPresent(testInt);
            } else {
                presentNode.rightChild.isPresent(testInt);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] integers = new int[size];
    Arrays.sort(integers);
    Node binarySearchTree = createBSTFromSortedArray(integers, 0, size - 1);
    if (binarySearchTree.isPresent(testInt)) {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No");
    }
    in.close();
}

private static Node createBSTFromSortedArray(int[] integers, int start, int end) {
    if (end < start) {
        return null;
    }
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    Node binarySearchTree = new Node(integers[mid]);
    binarySearchTree.leftChild = createBSTFromSortedArray(integers, start, mid - 1);
    binarySearchTree.rightChild = createBSTFromSortedArray(integers, mid + 1, end);
    return binarySearchTree;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `isPresent` method, you are ignoring the results of calling `isPresent` on the `left` and `right` children.  Assign the `left` or `right` child to `presentNode` as appropriate.

Change

```
} else if (testInt < presentNode.getValue()) {
     presentNode.leftChild.isPresent(testInt);
} else {
     presentNode.rightChild.isPresent(testInt);
}
```

to

```
} else if (testInt < presentNode.getValue()) {
    presentNode = presentNode.leftChild;
} else {
    presentNode = presentNode.rightChild;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that worked. Thanks a lot. Can't believe I missed that! You saved a lot of time for me.